# Symfony routing get parameter from url

Tags: symfony, routes

I want to get a parameter from a link in Symfony.

When I visit the URL, I should be forwarded to the index page. I want to `get` the value of the token parameter. The link looks like this:

```
http://www.myapp.com/?token=khdfhgkdfjghjdfgd354dfgdfg454dfg
```

In my controller, I should get the value of the `token`.
But how do I do this using the `GET` method?

Answer (score 6):

This is a simple task, simply type hint the Request object in your controller method like so...

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="index")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $token = $request->query->get('token');

        // ... 
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/{token}", name="index_with_token")
     */
    public function indexWithTokenAction(Request $request, $token)
    {    
        // ... 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;


/**
* @Route("/your-url/{token}",
* defaults={"token"="...."}, name="url_token")
*/
public function yourAction(Request $request) {

    // $_GET parameters
    $request->query->get('name'); // in your case name is token

    // $_POST parameters
    $request->request->get('name');

}
```

Comment: Or you can put $token in the method arguments and symfony will automatically assign the value to the argument.

Comment: @Emna However, I strongly the council you to make some efforts and take a look at the official documentation!

Comment: What does the `Request` before the parameter `$request` mean?

Comment: @PomCanys It's typehint (Check out the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)). Symfony uses that in order to know which action parameter is the request parameter.

Comment: @EmanuelOster thank you for your explanation. So is `Request` something that only Symphony uses? Because on the PHP documentation I couldn't find `Request` as a valid type.

Comment: @PomCanys Of course it's a valid type in the documentation: _Class/interface name_ ;)
But yes, `Request` is a Symfony specific class.